# SSH fails after Port change on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ssh, centos7

After changing the port.

And restarting the SSH service, it failed on me.

I got the following info when I ran `systemctl status sshd.service`:

```
sshd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
sshd.service failed.
```

Any suggestions on how do I fix this (newb here)?

Comment: what port did you try change it to?

Comment: @Orphans Port 977...opened the firewall and everything but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ports under 1000 is reserved for other services, set it to 1000 or higher.

Comment: @Orphans Is there any way I can unreserve it?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/linux-allowing-an-user-to-listen-to-a-port-below-1024

Comment: Did you adjust the SELinux policy as the comment in the configuration file hints?

Comment: @Jakuje I'm not really sure how to setup `setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/program` to work for sshd. Can you help?

Comment: No. That is something different. It says: *If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell SELinux about this change.*
`# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER`

Comment: Whatever Orphans said doesn't apply here, and you should stop trying to do that. It will not solve your problem. @Jakuje appears to have figured out the issue.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Like this: `semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 977`?

Comment: @Jakuje I just add `977` for `#portnumber` and thats it?

Comment: Yes, that should do the job. Run it as a root and try to restart the service again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To allow `sshd` running on different port than default 22, you need to adjust SELinux policy, otherwise it will be blocked from binding the port. The procedure is explained just few lines above the line you were changing in `sshd_config`:

```
# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
```

Therefore in your case, just run from root shell (or with `sudo`):

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 977
```

and then try to restart the service again. If it will not solve your problems, have a look into the logs and update the question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as the OP on Centos 7.5 but semanage wasn't found; solution is to install `policycoreutils-python` yum install policycoreutils-python [https://www.ostechnix.com/linux-troubleshooting-semanage-command-not-found-in-centos-7rhel-7/](https://www.ostechnix.com/linux-troubleshooting-semanage-command-not-found-in-centos-7rhel-7/)